# Typescript: ensure object literal extends interface but return real object type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a function in typescript that returns an object which must extend a given interface, but i want the function to return the real type of the created object.
The reason is that the object in the function might change in the future and i want to make sure it will always have the minimum props required in the interface.

example:

```js
interface MustExtend {
  a: string;
}

function myFunc() {
  // I want to enforce res to extend type MustExtend
  // right now it can be of type {something: 3} and compiler will allow it
  const res = {a: 'hello', b: 2} 
  return res;
}

const c = myFunc(); // c should be of type {a: string, b: number}, or the more concrete type generated by method
```

EDIT:

I will try to clarify my question. I want the result type of the function to be inferred from the returned object without specifying the type of `res`, since it's generated by many computations:

```js
interface MustExtend {
  a: string;
}

function myFunc() {
  // i want to enforce res to extend type MustExtend
  // right now it can be of type {something: 3} (no 'a' at all)
  // and i want to make sure it exists
  const res = {
    a: 'hello', 
    b: 2, 
    // a million more properties here that can change over time
  } 
  return res;
}

const c = myFunc(); // c should be of type {a: string, b: number, ...other props}
```

Comment: Could you try explain better?
I thought I have an answer for you but as more as I read your question, I am getting more confused.

Comment: essentially i want my method to return a value as specific as possible for an object that's created within the method (not just `MustExtend` interface). in my example i can do:
`const res = {somethingElse: 5}` and compiler won't shout because i didn't enforce anything. i want the best of both worlds :)

Comment: `function myFunc(): MustExtend {`

Comment: @nubinub this will not work, because `c` will be of type `MustExtend` and not of type `{a: string, b: number}`, compiler will not recognise property `b` which exists on returned value

Comment: `interface C extends MustExtend {
  b: number;
}`
and then
`function myFunc(): C {`

Comment: the idea is that i don't have to specify the type of `res` explicitly, since it could have many properties (in my real case above 20). the function would simply infer the type of `res` and return it

Comment: Are you looking for something like:
`function myFunc<T>(input: T): T & MustExtend { ...`

Comment: not exactly, because the `T` is not dependant on input. it's as if i want something like this:
`function myFunc(): infer T extends MustExtend { ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some tinkering i found how to do it:

```
interface MustExtend {
  a: string;
}

function myFunc(): typeof res extends MustExtend ? typeof res : never {
  // i want to enforce res to extend type MustExtend
  // right now it can be of type {something: 3} (no 'a' at all)
  // and i want to make sure it exists
  const res = {
    a: 'hello', 
    b: 2, 
    // a million more properties here that can change over time
  } 
  return res;
}

const c = myFunc(); // c should be of type {a: string, b: number, ...other props}
```

Apparently typescript can get the type of the object in method during compile time and use it in the method types. Using it this way i don't have to specify the type of `res` in advance and also ensure that it has all the properties from the interface

Answer (score 3):

You can use a trick.
Force Typescript to convert res into `MustExtend`, but then you convert it back to preserve the original type:

```
interface MustExtend {
  a: string;
}

function myFunc() {
  const res  = {
    a: 'hello', // will cause TS error if you remove this line
    b: 2,
    1: '1',
  } 

  return res as MustExtend as typeof res; // convert and convert back
}

const c = myFunc(); // will have full type
```

Comment: that's a cool trick too, compiler will fail you on first cast if it's incompatible. the thing i like less is that if i do some more complex logic i might miss properties in these casting.

Comment: what do you mean "miss properties"?

Comment: i usually try to avoid castings since it tends to cause problem with mismatching properties, although it can't really happen in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Your function already returns the most general type possible. Enforcing that this type matches the interface is done when you use the return value. For instance you can have a check like this:

```js
const check: () => MustExtend = () => myFunc()
// or
const check1: MustExtend | undefined = undefined as ReturnType<typeof myFunc> | undefined;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=20&ssc=91&pln=19&pc=48#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIFcDOYCiAPSEAE2QG8AoZZOALmWylAHMBucgX3PJnRATGAB7EMgC2ATwBivBAAoAlGUrIA9CuTBkAdzjhkYQcgggYgqEmRQImfYYgFjJMOIAOKDNnyEiytZeBMABZgyCCCWhohCLrIAEYogjD6riikmIKiEGCBzHQAzOzIsmHIAORwpdQhcAA2NfK%206rokmjp6BmJwANYomOhWkUZ4wNiYygjC2JbWyAC8SlRUtGWBEHWCpQA0yMpUsXQATNu7qk1iwHVCIqJmKC5Qgm5QAjOrA9lwUTEIgbpMCQA3aD6YCZZSFZRWMD9ERWTBsTjkCYgKYIOZiKQyBQsU7INGYQKCdA1EjxZCJZJuMjLBjMbb7ULoUTxKDbAB0HME2WB90emERyNRqwQXQADHQFHMAHxoLC4BzEdGS2YyiTSPgKJGTKLCroARjoHnl3mQAB9kLwiBAYKAICR5pbrbaSHAbAAlLIwgAqKQAPM43BS1TIZebHTaQHa2EA)

As far as I know, if you need to enforce the test at type level only (without generating javascript objects), you need an external tool like
[dtslint](https://koerbitz.me/posts/unit-testing-typescript-types-with-dtslint.html).

Answer (score 0):

Fuction return type definition can be a class type, or interface. If you are defining a function like this:

```js
function myFunc(): MustExtend {}
```

where `MustExtend` is an interface, it will return object, that complies with interface `MustExtend`. But returned object will still have its type, which can be checked with `instanceof`. Actually, in typescript you cannot check if returned object complies with the interface you want - `instanceof` does not work on interfaces. So you have to check the actual type of the object. With this definition you can return any object inside, that complies with `MustExtend` (terrible name, name interfaces on nouns :) and later you can check (if you want) what exactly type it was. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
interface MustExtend {
  a: string;
}

const c = {
  a: 'hello',
  b: 2,
}
// Ensure `c` conforms to MustExtend. (`c` will continue to have its original type)
c as MustExtend // Works!

const d = {
  x: 1,
  y: 2,
}
// Ensure `d` conforms to MustExtend
d as MustExtend // Error! Property 'a' is missing
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=18&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIFcDOYCiAPSEAE2QG8AoZZOALmWylAHMBucgX3PIQHsRtkCZAF4ylanQDkACwgAbOT0kAacQCM6AJlWcA9LuQ5%206KCgAGCM4L4weUALaZkYHmiy4CEYgDpkACgsrAHdgBWtwUHQUF2RpOAA3FGAwJztgJlA4OWcATwAHCABKbmonDGx8QhJ9ZAB1OwBrTABCLl5%20MGQSUQoqPDoARlUqHK0dchqjTBNzIit22wcnGPKPKvISODL3Sq9qgxwoKDtm5AAFY4KoMBzkSThJZGAne2fMZi4gA)

Comment: if c is going to be `const c = {a: 'hello', b: 2, x: 3}` then running `const c = myFunc();` will not return the actual type of c, but the type of `MustExtend` which is not what i want. check my answer, you get the actual type of `c` there

Answer (score 0):

I happen to land on this question while looking for alternative but it seems like I found a concise version myself already:

```js
function defineConfig<T extends Config>(config: T): T {
  return config
}
```

I was trying to define a config (for [TailwindCSS](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss)) that should follow an interface but I need the concrete type so I can reference it on my code.